# Reset Database/Tables using EF(Core) Migrations from Code

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I'm building an Data Import tool and need to reset the tables before importing data.

I'm thinking the fastest way to do this is by deleting all tables using Migrations by calling the Down method until the tables are gone.

in the Package Manager Console i've been writing **Update-Database -Migration:0** and then right after call **Update-Database**

I've seen that i can call **.Database.Migrate()** on my Context - but it doesn't take any parameters.

so how do i get this working ?

ps. I've searched google and stackoverflow and the usual answer is to use Package Manager Console or some CLI call - but i believe this should be possible in C#, right ?

Comment: Use the approach from the duplicate post to reset the database to its initial state. Alternatively you could use `.Database.EnsureDeleted()`, but it will delete also the database (if exists) along with its tables. In both cases, use `.Database.Migrate()` afterwards to get database populated with latest model schema.

Comment: Hi Ivan - The duplicate answer was exactly what i needed and i figured out the Migrate() to deploy the tables again !